# Windows' System process trying to connect to unknown computers

Tags: windows-7, internet

I'm running Windows 7. My computer keeps trying to connect to servers I've never heard of. I block each attempt. The firewall displays "System" as the offending application.

This started soon after connecting my computer directly to the modem (there was previously a router in the way). I have done this before, but this is the first time I see this happening.

Here are some of the computers that it has tried to connect to:

- 51.243-broadband.acttv.in
- 78-58-196-217.static.zebra.lt
- pc-93-123.akademiki.uni.torun.pl
- lan-213-159-45-247.vln.skynet.lt
- lan26-968.elektra.lt
- ctv-213-164-96-120.vinita.lt
- 148-25.plus.kerch.net
- host-88-132-160-169.prtelecom.hu

They look like telecommunication companies to me.
What I want to know is which service is doing this and why.

Please let me know if there's anything I forgot to mention.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
I have disabled all of the services that I could (except those that are required for a working Internet access) and the strange behaviour stopped. After a reboot (all of the services that were running before, are running again), the behaviour in question did not continue. I can't get it to do that again, so I'll probably never know what was happening.

Comment: **The first step disable network sharing.**

Comment: @Ramhound I have.

Comment: Your system is most likely compromised. As a precaution I suggest immediately disconnecting it from all networks and changing all the passwords you used on that system.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you got a virus/troyan/worm which is trying to copy itself to other sites or just attacking them. Having connected your PC without a firewall could have been the way in. You have to do a virus scan. You can try to find the process running this in your command line:

```
C:>netstat -nab

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:22             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [sshd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:25             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [PUTTY.EXE]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [PUTTY.EXE]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [PUTTY.EXE]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    192.168.1.100:27831    173.194.42.54:443      ESTABLISHED
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    192.168.1.100:28031    198.252.206.25:443     ESTABLISHED
 [chrome.exe]
  TCP    192.168.1.100:28033    173.194.42.35:443      TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.100:28035    190.93.246.58:80       ESTABLISHED  
 [chrome.exe]
```

You have to find the target IP in the **Foreign Address** column. Most probably the State will show TIME_WAIT. Certainly it won't show LISTENING nor ESTABLISHED. The process owning the connection is printed in the line below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The process is just listed as "[System]".
I have scanned memory with ESET Smart Security, but it didn't find anything.

Comment: Windows has no real process named System as far as I remember (I'm on Linux right now). Look for a process named System in the Task Manager and check the path to that executable file. If windows default task manager doesn't help you, try installing [Daphne](http://www.drk.com.ar/daphne.php) for finding the executable.

Comment: Windows does have a System process. Its PID is 4. Process Explorer does not display any executable file for it, but there are some files (.exe and .sys extensions) listed under the Threads bar.

I compared the checksums of the files with those on a computer that doesn't talk to strangers and they're mostly the same, except for some nvidia driver files, which makes sense, because they have different graphics cards.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Its path is **"(WIN)\system32\ntoskrnl.exe"**. But first check there is no a duplicate process in task manager with the same name but different PID. If there is one, that must be the virus/troyan. But, of course, the virus could have infected your Windows kernel. Which could explain why you see System in the netstat. Or maybe the virus is messing with netstat output for hiding himself.

Comment: There is only one System process. Since the files (including ntoskrnl.exe) are unchanged, the malware must inject itself into the process during or after boot, right? There's nothing suspicious in msconfig.exe under Startup, but I don't know how more sophisticated methods would work.

Comment: You have to scan your HDD with another computer or with a booteable antivirus.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried two bootable antivirus applications (Windows Defender Offline and BitDefender Rescue CD), but neither could find anything.

Comment: I see. But there is no doubt about it. There is something in side your  Windows trying to connect outside. Which looks like worm behavior. If antiviruses aren't capable of removing it you will have to reinstall.